# passing a variable into a function

Tags: jquery, function, variables

Title may make this question seem simpler than it really is.  First off, my knowledge, familiarity and skill levels with jQuery is shaky at best, so chances are i'm just trying to go about something in a stupid way that would only make sense to a noob.

I have a php generated page that builds a bunch of text fields based on external data.  These fields are to be converted to kind of a hybrid jQuery UI Autocomplete/Combobox field (like a combo but allows free text).  I'm stuck when trying to assign the .click(function(...)) to the dropdown button and I believe it has to do witht the fact that I'm executing the jQuery to convert all of the textfields via a for loop and var i isn't being properly passed into the .click function.

Here is the full test page that I'm working with (almost all of the HTML and js arrays will be generated via php):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" href="../includes/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
        <style>
    .ui-button { margin-left: -1px;width:18px; }
    .ui-button-icon-only .ui-button-text { padding: 0; }
    button.ui-button-icon-only {width:18px;height:21px;}
    .ui-autocomplete-input { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="results.php">
    <input class="TC_1" type="text" name="TC_1_1" value="E02_04" />
    <script>
          var availableTags = [['test1','test2','test3']];
    </script>
    <br/>
    <input class="TC_1" type="text" name="TC_2_1" />
    <script>
          availableTags.push (['test5','test7','test9']);
    </script>
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
  var input = new Array();
var i = 1;

$('.TC_1').each(function(index) {

input[i] = $("[name=TC_"+i+"_1]").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags[i-1],
    select: function(){alert("selected");},
    minLength: 0
}).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");


$("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>")
    .attr("tabIndex", -1)
    .attr("title", "Show All Items")
    .insertAfter(input[i])
    .button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        },
        text: false
    })
    .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
    .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")
    .click(function() {
    var $input = $(this).before();
    if ($input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
        $input.autocomplete( "close" );
        return;
    }
    $(this).blur();
    $input.autocomplete("search", "" );
    $input.focus();
});

    i++;
});
  //]]>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:  Sorry I forgot to add that i'm getting "Error: input[i] is undefined
Line: 62"**

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the problem is?

Comment: You have to create closures to use correct value of i. [Here](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/) you can find about closures at "The infamous loop problem" section

Comment: By the way, you have `index` variable from `each` function. Use it instead of `i` variable. Of course you can change it's name to `i`. If you do this change don't forget to remove last incrementation, each function does it for you.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, i'm having a difficult time trying to explain the issue while keeping the explanation simple and my lack of jQuery experience is not helping.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I updated my answer after new source code.

Give it a try.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" href="../includes/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .ui-button { margin-left: -1px;width:18px; }
    .ui-button-icon-only .ui-button-text { padding: 0; }
    button.ui-button-icon-only {width:18px;height:21px;}
    .ui-autocomplete-input { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="results.php">
      <input class="TC_1" type="text" name="TC_1_1" value="E02_04" />
      <br/>
      <input class="TC_1" type="text" name="TC_2_1" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      $('.TC_1').each(function(i) {
        var availableTags = [];
        availableTags.push(['test1','test2','test3']);
        availableTags.push(['test5','test7','test9']);

        $(this).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags[i],
          select: function(){alert("selected");},
          minLength: 0
        }).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

        $("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>")
          .attr("tabIndex", -1)
          .attr("title", "Show All Items")
          .insertAfter(this)
          .button({
              icons: {
                  primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
              },
              text: false
          })
          .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
          .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")
          .click(function() {
            var $input = $(this).prev();
            $input.autocomplete("destroy");
            $input.val("search").select();
          });
      });
      //]]>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not getting an error anymore, but when I click on the buttons it doesn't show the drop down.

Comment: You don't need to add availableTags between inputs. So I changed that a bit and made some improvements.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still doesn't work.  The reason why the availabletags is between the fields is because I was want to simulate how php was going to add those values.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it figured out, well sort of.  I had a feeling that the following workaround would work, however I was kind of hoping that there would be a more elegant way of doing this.

```
    .click(function() {

//Get the name for the target field:
var target = $(this).attr('id');
target = target.substr(3);

    // close if already visible
    if ($("[name=TC_"+target+"]").autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
    $("[name=TC_"+target+"]").autocomplete( "close" );
         return;
    }
    $(this).blur();
    $("[name=TC_"+target+"]").autocomplete("search", "" ); //where the error occurs
    $("[name=TC_"+target+"]").focus();
});
```

And I also gave the button a unique name to correspond with the field...

```
$("<button id='bt_"+i+"_1' type='button'>&nbsp;</button>")
```

Thanks for the help guys.